# Date.js culture info is confusing me

Tags: javascript, date, culture, cultureinfo

I'm including date.js (from datejs.com) and the en-IE culture info script.

If I call `alert(Date.CultureInfo.dateElementOrder)` I see the correct `dmy`, but if I try to interpret the date `02/03/01` I get `3 Jan 2001` and not `2 Feb 2001`. I'm not sure whether this is a bug in date.js or a problem with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation was confusing me (or I hadn't read it right).

I thought I should include date.js and en-IE.js. In fact, the right thing to do is to include date-en-IE.js, a file I hadn't even noticed existed before.

As usual with datejs, the downloadable file on the front of the site is a year or so out of date, but a live version exists if you dig for it in the svn trunk.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that the page was old too, first I couldn't realiaze why it wasn't working.